# How are android 3.0 browser layouts done?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

First some screens:

Default:
[image: default]

Nice effect:
[image: nice effect]

Cool hiding:
[image: cool hiding]

Detecting hidden:
[image: detecting hidden]

The question is how to do this cool hiding? As you see, the navigation bar disappears as the WebView (?) is scrolling up. I don't have a clue how they did do that... Any ideas?

And how do they detect that the scrollbar should be hidden? When it's hidden cool arrow appears on tab.

Comment: I don't really see the difference between your screen shots. Maybe you should mark the important parts?